# Проблема с вещественными числами в FORTRAN77

Tags: float, fortran, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Имеется следующий код:

```
  PROGRAM TEST 
  DX = .01D0
  DY = 89.99D0

  PRINT *, DX + DY
  IF ((DX+DY).EQ.90.0D0) THEN
  PRINT *, 'yes'
  ENDIF

  READ *
  END
```

Он выводит на экран:

```
90.0000000
```

Но не выводит YES. Я знаю, что во всём этом виновато представление вещественных чисел. И то что число 0,01 представляется в виде 0,00999999999. Но не знаю как решить проблему.

Как я могу сделать так, чтобы она выводила мне YES?
Почему она выводит говорит, что сумма равна 90, при выводе на экран, а при сравнении не равна?

Answer (score 0):

Очень долго разбираясь в проблеме вещественных чисел, и найдя экспертов в этом вопросе, я решил проблему. 
Дело в том, что у вещественных чисел такая проблема, что их нельзя сравнивать на равенство, это в 99% случаев даёт абсолютно неправильный ответ.
Вместо:

```
IF ((DX+DY).EQ.90.0D0)
```

Нужно писать:

```
IF (ABS((DX+DY)-90.0D0) .LT. 1D-4)
```

А теперь по русски:
Нельзя сравнить два числа с плавающей точкой на равенство(==), нужно найти модуль разности текущего числа и числа, с которым мы сравниваем. Этот модуль разности называется **абсолютной погрешностью измерения**. Так вот, когда мы находим погрешность, мы должны её сравнить с малым числом. Это число нужно выбрать исходя из того, сколько знаков после запятой мы хотим сохранить.

На моём конкретном примере 89.99 складывается с 0.0099999999999 и получается 90.0000000001.

Естественно это число не равно 90.0

Но если найти абсолютную погрешность:

90.0000000001 - 90.0 = 0.0000000001

Её можно сравнить (как я это делаю в примере) с числом 0.0001.

```
IF (0.0000000001 < 0.0001) THEN
```

Наше число равно числу 90 с точность 4 знаков после запятой.

Но естественно 4 знака это мало. Исходя из официальных данных тип REAL(он же float, он же число с плавающей точкой одинарной точности), на который отводится 4 байта, имеет 7 значащих цифр. А тип DOUBLE PERCISION(он же double, REAL*8, число с плавающей точкой двойной точности), на который отводится 8 байт, имеет 15 значащих цифр.

Comment: Эта тема с неточностью float и сравнениями регулярно тут обсуждается применительно к разным языкам. Вчера опять про Python похожее было.